# Android incoming call notification: play ringtone through MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-notifications, incoming-call

*TL;DR how to start a notification in a channel that has a sound but play the actual sound with a MediaPlayer?*

I work on an Android calling app. The incoming calls are displayed via full screen intent notifications. Notifications are dispatched to a channel with a sound and vibration.

I came across an issue on OnePlus devices with their "pocket mode". Basically if you put your phone into the pocket and receive a call via a notification, the pocket mode will silence it (i.e. you don't hear the ringing).

This does not happen if I play the ringtone with a MediaPlayer.

Now, the question is how to avoid the notification and the MediaPlayer play at the same time. I m certain that this is possible because Signal [does it](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/main/app/src/main/java/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/webrtc/audio/IncomingRinger.java). But I fail to understand how they do it. They [create their channels](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/36b1f2816ce2e7afebe5e53d541f9613d4b98146/app/src/main/java/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/notifications/NotificationChannels.java#L598) the normal way and the incoming call notification is [built](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/36b1f2816ce2e7afebe5e53d541f9613d4b98146/app/src/main/java/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/webrtc/CallNotificationBuilder.java#L39) the same way I tried.

For some reason once the notification is displayed it does not emit any sound nor vibration.

Does anyone have a clue how they managed to do it?

P.S.: I tried to use `setSilent(true)` on my notification but in this case the system does not display the notification at all, it launches the full screen intent immediately.

N.b.: I checked all stackoverflow issues that resembled even remotely what I am trying to figure out. Those that matched the description never got a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I love asking questions on stackoverflow: the moment you post it you find an answer yourself.

Apparently if you set the `mode` to [MODE_IN_CALL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#MODE_IN_CALL) or [MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION) notification will be silenced.